# number of ways in which $2$ persons seated next to each other in $2$ column

Tags: probability

> $16$ people have purchase ticket for movie.They are seated randomly in $2$ column of $8$.What is the probability that Alex and mary who have movie tickets , seated next to each other.

What i try: Total ways is arranging $16$  peoples in $16$ places which equals $=16!$

And favourable ways:

If alex and mary in $1$ st column. Then no. Of ways in which they seated next to each other $7$ ways. Same goes for second column.

So favourable wayas $ =7+7=14$

So required probability $$\frac{14}{16!}$$

Can anyone please explain me is my solution is right.

If not then how do i solve it, Help me please.

Comment: Yes Ross Millikan it was typing mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your count of favorable cases is quite low.  Alex can go anywhere, giving $16$ choices.  Then Mary has only one place to sit, but then the rest can go anywhere, giving $14!$ choices.

Comment: Isn't it possible for Mary to have more than one place to sit, depending on where Alex originally sits? I'm getting $$\frac{{2 \choose 1}2!{14 \choose 6}7!8!}{16!}=\frac{7}{60}$$

Comment: No, there is only one place next to Alex.  That is the point of $2$ columns of $8$.  Next to does not include in front of or behind.  If you seat Mary just after Alex, it is clear she has to sit in one of $15$ available seats, so it should be $\frac 1{15}$

Comment: Oh okay, gotcha. I was thinking two rows of 8, my bad. If the problem was two rows of 8 instead of two columns of 8, would my answer be correct?

Comment: No, it must be less than $\frac 2{15}$, because that would be the answer if Mary always had two choices and sometimes (when Alex sits on the end) she will only have one.  You did not explain where you got your expression, so I cannot see what is wrong.

Comment: $\frac{7}{60}$ is less than $\frac{2}{15}$, and I'm regarding {Alex,Mary} as a single unit whose seats can be arranged in 2! ways

Comment: You are right about the comparison.  It is about right, then.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to check my answer. Very much appreciated.